# C++ pointers not accessing correct memory address, instead accessing random memory locations

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I'm learning C++ and I'm wondering if anyone can explain some strange behaviour I'm seeing.

I'm currently learning memory management and have been playing around with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

// pass back by pointer (old C++)
const int array_size = 1e6; // determines size of the random number array

vector<int> *RandomNumbers1()
{
    vector<int> *random_numbers = new vector<int>[array_size]; // allocate memory on the heap...
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        int b = rand();
        (*random_numbers).push_back(b); // ...and fill it with random numbers
    }
    return random_numbers; // return pointer to heap memory
}

int main (){
    vector<int> *random_numbers = RandomNumbers1();
    for (int i = 0; i < (*random_numbers).size(); i++){
        cout << (*random_numbers)[i] + "\n";     
    }
    delete random_numbers;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is get a pointer to a vector containing random integers by calling the `RandomNumbers1()` function, and then print each random number on a new line.

However, when I run the above code, instead of printing out a random number, I get all sorts of random information. It seems as though the code is accessing random places in memory and printing out the contents.

Now I know that I'm doing something stupid here - I have an `int` and I am adding the string `"\n"` to it. If I change the code in `main()` to the following, it works fine:

```
int main (){
    vector<int> *random_numbers = RandomNumbers1();
    for (int i = 0; i < (*random_numbers).size(); i++){
        cout << to_string((*random_numbers)[i]) + "\n";   
    }
}
```

However I just can't understand the behaviour I'm getting with the "wrong" code - i.e. how adding the string `"\n"` to `(*random_numbers)[i]`
causes the program to access random areas of memory, instead of where my pointer is pointing to. Surely I have de-referenced the pointer and accessed the element at position `i` before "adding" `"\n"` to it? So how is the program instead accessing a totally different memory address?

Comment: As a tip: You can dereference a pointer with `->` instead of doing `(*ptr).func()`. Just write: `ptr->func()`

Comment: `new vector<int>[array_size];` creates an array of vectors, but you probably don't want to allocate a vector dynamically at all...

Comment: Unrelated, but did you mean to only use one of the `vector`s that you allocated?  All but one are left empty.  Also, you need to use `delete[]` since you used `new[]`.

Answer (score 4):

`"\n"` is a string literal. It is an array and it is converted to a pointer pointing at its first element in your expression.

`(*random_numbers)[i]` is an integer.

Adding a pointer to an integer means that advance the pointer by the integer.

This will drive the pointer to out-of-range because `"\n"` has only 2 elements (`'\n'` and `'\0'`) but the numbers returnd from the `rand()` function are likely to be larger than 2.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code.

- you are using `delete` instead of `delete[]` to free the array allocated with `new[]`.
- you are creating an array of 1000000 `vector`s, but populating only the 1st `vector` with 1000000 integers.  You probably meant to create just 1 `vector` instead.
- you can and should use the `->` operator when accessing an object's members via a pointer.  Using the `*` and `.` operators will also work, but is more verbose and harder to read/code for.
- you are trying to print a `"\n"` after each number, but you are using the `+` operator when you should be using the `<<` operator instead.  You can't append a string literal to an integer (well, you can, but it will invoke **pointer arithmetic** and thus the result will not be what you want, as you have seen).

With that said, try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

const int array_size = 1e6; // determines size of the random number array

vector<int>* RandomNumbers1()
{
    vector<int> *random_numbers = new vector<int>;
    random_numbers->reserve(array_size);

    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i)
    {
        int b = rand();
        random_numbers->push_back(b);
    }

    return random_numbers;
}

int main (){
    vector<int> *random_numbers = RandomNumbers1();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < random_numbers->size(); ++i){
        cout << (*random_numbers)[i] << "\n";
    }

    /* alternatively:
    for (int number : *random_numbers){
        cout << number << "\n";
    }
    */

    delete[] random_numbers;
}
```

However, if you are going to return a pointer to dynamic memory, you really should wrap it inside a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, and let it deal with the `delete` for you:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

const int array_size = 1e6; // determines size of the random number array

unique_ptr<vector<int>> RandomNumbers1()
{
    auto random_numbers = make_unique<vector<int>>();
    // or: unique_ptr<vector<int>> random_numbers(new vector<int>);

    random_numbers->reserve(array_size);

    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i)
    {
        int b = rand();
        random_numbers->push_back(b);
    }

    return random_numbers;
}

int main (){
    auto random_numbers = RandomNumbers1();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < random_numbers->size(); ++i){
        cout << (*random_numbers)[i] << "\n";
    }

    /* alternatively:
    for (int number : *random_numbers){
        cout << number << "\n";
    }
    */
}
```

Though, in this case, there is really no good reason to create the `vector` dynamically at all.  99% of the time, it is unnecessary and unwanted to use standard containers like that.  Since the `vector` manages dynamic memory internally, there is no reason for the `vector` itself to also be created in dynamic memory.  Return the `vector` by value instead, and let the compiler optimize the return for you.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

const int array_size = 1e6; // determines size of the random number array

vector<int> RandomNumbers1()
{
    vector<int> random_numbers;
    random_numbers.reserve(array_size);

    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i)
    {
        int b = rand();
        random_numbers.push_back(b);
    }

    return random_numbers;
}

int main (){
    vector<int> random_numbers = RandomNumbers1();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < random_numbers.size(); ++i){
        cout << random_numbers[i] << "\n";
    }

    /* alternatively:
    for (int number : random_numbers){
        cout << number << "\n";
    }
    */
}
```